# How to draw a brownian motion in R (Black Scholes Simulation)

Tags: r, ggplot2, finance, stock

I am trying to draw lines resembling a Brownian motion regarding the changes in the price of the Stock (stock path).

```
# Parameter Setting

S0<-1
r<-0.555
M<-1000 # the number of time steps
sigma<-0.5
T<-1 # Time to Expiration 
X<-1
N<-1000 # The number of simulations
dt<-T/M; # Calculate the time interval 

S<-matrix(0L, nrow = M+1, ncol =N)
ds<-matrix(0L, nrow = M, ncol = N)
S[1,]<-matrix(S0,1,N) # Initialize Stock 
Value

for (t in 1:M){
ds[t,]<- 
r*S[t,]*dt+sigma*sqrt(dt)*S[t,]*rnorm(N)
S[t+1,]<-ds[t,]+S[t,]
}
call_price<-pmax(S[M+1,]-X,0)
```

This is what I've done so far, but trying to express the equation for calculating the stock path is the problem.

Here is the equation:

[image: equation]

Moreover, what would be the best way to plot the graph showing the alterations in the price of the Stock in accordance to time?

Need a graph like this OR a graph with 5 paths of the stock price:

[image: Need a graph like this OR a graph with 5 paths of the stock price]

Comment: I don't understand the equation part. Do you want to write a latex-style equation in R?

Answer (score 1):

the easies way to plot one path of a Brownian motion is

```
set.seed(1)
dt <- 1/1000
M <- 1000
Bt <- cumsum(rnorm(M)) * sqrt(dt)


plot(1:M/M, Bt, type = "l")
```

Given one path a Brownian motion you can calculate the corresponding path of a geometrian Browian motion:

```
St <- S0 * exp(sigma * Bt + (mu - sigma^2/ 2) * 1:M/M)
```

Alternatively, I can recommend the `ESGtoolkit` package:

```
library(ESGtoolkit)
eps <- simshocks(100, horizon = 1, frequency = "daily", family = 1, par = 0)
St <- simshocks(100, horizon = 1, frequency = "daily", model = "GBM",
                 theta1 = mu, theta2 = sigma, eps = eps[[1]])
```